# VSTS API returning security namespaces with duplicate name

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using the VSTS API [Security Namespace Query endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/security/security%20namespaces/query) and am getting odd data back. I noticed the change this week because it broke the script I have been working on.

> GET: https://*siteroot*.visualstudio.com/_apis/securitynamespaces/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/?api-version=4.1-preview

Specifically, a second namespace started showing up this week with the name 'ReleaseManagement' (see below). I am using a script to call this endpoint and am now unsure how to parse between the two 'Release Management' namespaces.

- This seems like a bug to me. What is the best approach to getting this resolved?
- If/until there is a fix, would the best fix be to just hardcode the GUID?

Any thoughts or tips to help me in move forward?
Thanks!

```
 {
"count": 58,
"value": [
...
...
...
{
    "namespaceId": "7c7d32f7-0e86-4cd6-892e-b35dbba870bd",
    "name": "ReleaseManagement",
    "displayName": "ReleaseManagement",
    "separatorValue": "/",
    "elementLength": -1,
    "writePermission": 0,
    "readPermission": 1,
    "dataspaceCategory": "ReleaseManagement",
    "actions": [
        {
            "bit": 1,
            "name": "ViewTaskEditor",
            "displayName": "View task editor",
            "namespaceId": "7c7d32f7-0e86-4cd6-892e-b35dbba870bd"
        },
        {
            "bit": 2,
            "name": "ViewCDWorkflowEditor",
            "displayName": "View CD work flow editor",
            "namespaceId": "7c7d32f7-0e86-4cd6-892e-b35dbba870bd"
        },
        {
            "bit": 4,
            "name": "ExportReleaseDefinition",
            "displayName": "Export release definition",
            "namespaceId": "7c7d32f7-0e86-4cd6-892e-b35dbba870bd"
        },
        {
            "bit": 8,
            "name": "ViewLegacyUI",
            "displayName": "View legacy UI",
            "namespaceId": "7c7d32f7-0e86-4cd6-892e-b35dbba870bd"
        },
        {
            "bit": 16,
            "name": "DeploymentSummaryAcrossProjects",
            "displayName": "Deployment summary across projects",
            "namespaceId": "7c7d32f7-0e86-4cd6-892e-b35dbba870bd"
        },
        {
            "bit": 32,
            "name": "ViewExternalArtifactCommitsAndWorkItems",
            "displayName": "View external artifact commits and work items",
            "namespaceId": "7c7d32f7-0e86-4cd6-892e-b35dbba870bd"
        }
    ],
    "structureValue": 1,
    "extensionType": null,
    "isRemotable": false,
    "useTokenTranslator": false,
    "systemBitMask": 0
},
{
    "namespaceId": "c788c23e-1b46-4162-8f5e-d7585343b5de",
    "name": "ReleaseManagement",
    "displayName": "ReleaseManagement",
    "separatorValue": "/",
    "elementLength": -1,
    "writePermission": 512,
    "readPermission": 0,
    "dataspaceCategory": "ReleaseManagement",
    "actions": [
        {
            "bit": 1,
            "name": "ViewReleaseDefinition",
            "displayName": "View release definition",
            "namespaceId": "c788c23e-1b46-4162-8f5e-d7585343b5de"
        },
        {
            "bit": 2,
            "name": "EditReleaseDefinition",
            "displayName": "Edit release definition",
            "namespaceId": "c788c23e-1b46-4162-8f5e-d7585343b5de"
        },
        {
            "bit": 4,
            "name": "DeleteReleaseDefinition",
            "displayName": "Delete release definition",
            "namespaceId": "c788c23e-1b46-4162-8f5e-d7585343b5de"
        },
        {
            "bit": 8,
            "name": "ManageReleaseApprovers",
            "displayName": "Manage release approvers",
            "namespaceId": "c788c23e-1b46-4162-8f5e-d7585343b5de"
        },
        {
            "bit": 16,
            "name": "ManageReleases",
            "displayName": "Manage releases",
            "namespaceId": "c788c23e-1b46-4162-8f5e-d7585343b5de"
        },
        {
            "bit": 32,
            "name": "ViewReleases",
            "displayName": "View releases",
            "namespaceId": "c788c23e-1b46-4162-8f5e-d7585343b5de"
        },
        {
            "bit": 64,
            "name": "CreateReleases",
            "displayName": "Create releases",
            "namespaceId": "c788c23e-1b46-4162-8f5e-d7585343b5de"
        },
        {
            "bit": 128,
            "name": "EditReleaseEnvironment",
            "displayName": "Edit release environment",
            "namespaceId": "c788c23e-1b46-4162-8f5e-d7585343b5de"
        },
        {
            "bit": 256,
            "name": "DeleteReleaseEnvironment",
            "displayName": "Delete release environment",
            "namespaceId": "c788c23e-1b46-4162-8f5e-d7585343b5de"
        },
        {
            "bit": 512,
            "name": "AdministerReleasePermissions",
            "displayName": "Administer release permissions",
            "namespaceId": "c788c23e-1b46-4162-8f5e-d7585343b5de"
        },
        {
            "bit": 1024,
            "name": "DeleteReleases",
            "displayName": "Delete releases",
            "namespaceId": "c788c23e-1b46-4162-8f5e-d7585343b5de"
        },
        {
            "bit": 2048,
            "name": "ManageDeployments",
            "displayName": "Manage deployments",
            "namespaceId": "c788c23e-1b46-4162-8f5e-d7585343b5de"
        },
        {
            "bit": 4096,
            "name": "ManageReleaseSettings",
            "displayName": "Manage release settings",
            "namespaceId": "c788c23e-1b46-4162-8f5e-d7585343b5de"
        }
    ],
    "structureValue": 1,
    "extensionType": null,
    "isRemotable": false,
    "useTokenTranslator": false,
    "systemBitMask": 0
},
...
}
```

Comment: What's the type of the endpoint for you to query? And you queried by `GET https://siteroot.visualstudio.com/_apis/securitynamespaces/7c7d32f7-0e86-4cd6-892e-b35dbba870bd?api-version=4.1-preview`? Can you also share the response of the REST API `GET https://siteroot.visualstudio.com/{projectname}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=4.1-preview.1`?

Comment: Besides, there has an superfluous `/` after the securityNamespaceId, please remove it (`GET https://siteroot.visualstudio.com/_apis/securitynamespaces/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000?api-version=4.1-preview`) and have a try.

Comment: `GET https://siteroot.visualstudio.com/_apis/securitynamespaces/7c7d32f7-0e86-4cd6-892e-b35dbba870bd?api-version=4.1-preview` -> returns the first object in the json snippet pasted above.
`GET https://siteroot.visualstudio.com/{projectname}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=4.1-preview.1` -> returns data some more sensitve data about our subscriptions. I am not comfortable just pasting this on here. Is there anything specific I should expect to see here?
'Superflouos /` -> The payload did not change after removing the /

Comment: So can you explain the details how you get the securityNamespaceId `7c7d32f7-0e86-4cd6-892e-b35dbba870bd?

Comment: When querying the namespace endpoint with an empty guid, you can see all of the namespaces. Looking into this, I don't see this behavior noted in the API documentation so I am not actually sure where I got that info from. Probably an older version of this api's docs or a stackoverflow article. :) 
I do know however, that I depend on the query with the empty guid to get the namespace guids I need for my permissions script. And that this week an extra entry just appeared that seems malformed. I am thinking it is a bug but wanted to see if others noticed or had further info on it.

Answer (score 0):

The two security namespaces `ReleaseManagement` are exist with different read/write permissions and different actions.

Such as for the first `ReleaseManagement` security namespace (`7c7d32f7-0e86-4cd6-892e-b35dbba870bd`), it contains the actions `View task editor`, `View CD work flow editor`, `Export release definition` and `View legacy UI` etc. While for the second `ReleaseManagement` security namespace (`c788c23e-1b46-4162-8f5e-d7585343b5de`), it contains the actions like `View release definition`, `Edit release definition` and `Delete release definition` etc.

So you can parse the two security namespaces `ReleaseManagement` by read/write permissions or actions.